# Angular Service - Class variable instantiated values are lost

Tags: angular9

I'm trying to write a service class that listens for page visibility and provides the state change to the subscribed component(s). The service class has an instance variable **doc** that pretty much holds the current HTML document. I set this **doc** from the components **init** method and subscribed in the component to listen for page visibility state change. Even though in the debug window, I see the state change happen, the doc variable is null there and I'm not sure why.

Below is my service class

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export enum PageVisibilityState {
    Visible,
    Hidden
}

@Injectable()
export class PageVisibilityService {    
    doc: Document;
    hiddenString:string = "";
    visibilityChange:string=""; 
    pageVisibilityState: PageVisibilityState = PageVisibilityState.Visible;
    _pageVisibilityStateSubject: Subject<PageVisibilityState> = new Subject();

    constructor() {
        this.doc = null;
    }

    init(doc: Document) {
        this.doc = doc;
        // Set the name of the "hidden" property and the change event for visibility
        if (typeof doc.hidden !== "undefined") {
            this.hiddenString = "hidden";
            this.visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
        } else if (typeof doc["mozHidden"] !== "undefined") { // Firefox up to v17
            this.hiddenString = "mozHidden";
            this.visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
        } else if (typeof doc["webkitHidden"] !== "undefined") { // Chrome up to v32, Android up to v4.4, Blackberry up to v10
            this.hiddenString = "webkitHidden";
            this.visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
        }

        // Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
        if (typeof doc.addEventListener === "undefined" || typeof doc[this.hiddenString] === "undefined") {
            console.log("This demo requires a modern browser that supports the Page Visibility API.");
        } else {
            // Handle page visibility change   
            doc.addEventListener(this.visibilityChange, this.handleVisibilityChange, false);            
        }
    }

    private handleVisibilityChange() {
        if (typeof this.doc.hidden !== "undefined") { //***this.doc <-- is null here*** 
            this.hiddenString = "hidden";
            this.visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
        } else if (typeof this.doc["mozHidden"] !== "undefined") { // Firefox up to v17
            this.hiddenString = "mozHidden";
            this.visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
        } else if (typeof this.doc["webkitHidden"] !== "undefined") { // Chrome up to v32, Android up to v4.4, Blackberry up to v10
            this.hiddenString = "webkitHidden";
            this.visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
        }

        if (this.doc[this.hiddenString]) {
            this.pageVisibilityStateSubject.next(PageVisibilityState.Hidden);//**all instances are null**
        } else {
            this.pageVisibilityStateSubject.next(PageVisibilityState.Visible);
        }
    }

    get pageVisibilityStateSubject() : Subject<PageVisibilityState> {
        return this._pageVisibilityStateSubject;
    }

    set pageVisibilityStateSubject(src: Subject<PageVisibilityState>) {
        this._pageVisibilityStateSubject = src;
    }

    public getVisibilityState(): Subject<PageVisibilityState> {
        return this.pageVisibilityStateSubject;
    }

    dispose(): void {
        //Called once, before the instance is destroyed.
        //Add 'implements OnDestroy' to the class.
        this.doc = null;
    }
}
```

Here is my app.module.ts

```
//some imports removed for easy readability
import { PageVisibilityService } from './shared/services/page.visibility.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [//imports removed for easy readability ],
    declarations: [//removed for easy readability ],
    providers: [
//some removed for easy readability 
        PageVisibilityService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my component

```
import { PageVisibilityService, PageVisibilityState } from '../../../shared/services/page.visibility.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-team-consult-action-teamConsult',
  templateUrl: './team-consult-action.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./team-consult-action.component.scss'],
  animations: [routerTransition()]
})

export class TeamConsultActionComponent implements OnInit {
    pageVisibilityStateSubject: Subject<PageVisibilityState>;

constructor(
    public router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private pageVisibilityService: PageVisibilityService,
    private commonService: CommonService) {

    this.pageVisibilityService.init(document);
    this.pageVisibilityStateSubject = this.pageVisibilityService.pageVisibilityStateSubject;
    this.pageVisibilityStateSubject.subscribe((pageVisible: PageVisibilityState) => {
      console.log(`Current Page State is ${pageVisible === PageVisibilityState.Visible ? "Visible" : "Hidden"}`);
    });
}
```

In the console log, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'next')
    at HTMLDocument.handleVisibilityChange (page.visibility.service.ts:57:45)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41442:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398:1)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167:1)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:480:1)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621:1)
    at HTMLDocument.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone-evergreen.js:1647:1)
```

Can you please assist with what is causing my instances to lose their initializations?

**Update**

I understood the cause of null issue why when debugging, the console shows null. The reason is that the PageVisibilityChange which the windows invokes is handleVisibilityChange method (in my class). But window doesn't have reference to our initialized object and it therefore is not in our instance that this happens. So, a possible solution I think could be to store the instance in sessionStorage show how and use that instance reference back to push the state values. Anyone else have faced this issue and were able to resolve this? or let me know if there is a common class using which I could I achieve this.

Thanks,
Hemant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my issue is solved by making the methods and members static because with one tab, there is going to be one browser so safe to go with static option and below is the updated code just in case anyone wants to make use of it.

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export enum PageVisibilityState {
    Hidden = 0,
    Visible = 1
}

@Injectable()
export class PageVisibilityService {    
    static hiddenString:string = "";
    static pageVisibilityState: PageVisibilityState = PageVisibilityState.Visible;
    static _PageVisibilityStateSubject: Subject<PageVisibilityState> = new Subject();

    constructor() {
        var visibilityChange:string=""; 
        // Set the name of the "hidden" property and the change event for visibility
        if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
            PageVisibilityService.hiddenString = "hidden";
            visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
        } else if (typeof document["mozHidden"] !== "undefined") { // Firefox up to v17
            PageVisibilityService.hiddenString = "mozHidden";
            visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
        } else if (typeof document["webkitHidden"] !== "undefined") { // Chrome up to v32, Android up to v4.4, Blackberry up to v10
            PageVisibilityService.hiddenString = "webkitHidden";
            visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
        }

        // Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
        if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || typeof document[PageVisibilityService.hiddenString] === "undefined") {
            console.log("This demo requires a modern browser that supports the Page Visibility API.");
        } else {
            // Handle page visibility change   
            document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, PageVisibilityService.handleVisibilityChange, false);            
        }
    }

    static handleVisibilityChange() {
        if (document[PageVisibilityService.hiddenString]) {
            PageVisibilityService._PageVisibilityStateSubject.next(PageVisibilityState.Hidden);
        } else {
            PageVisibilityService._PageVisibilityStateSubject.next(PageVisibilityState.Visible);
        }
    }

    get PageVisibilityStateSubject() : Subject<PageVisibilityState> {
        return PageVisibilityService._PageVisibilityStateSubject;
    }

    set PageVisibilityStateSubject(src: Subject<PageVisibilityState>) {
        PageVisibilityService._PageVisibilityStateSubject = src;
    }
}
```